# How to add optional arguments with default values in Python using argparse?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I need to rewrite an arguments parser.The application has two modes: console and graphics. We can choose only one mode. Lately, the console version received two arguments: name of file with text and name of file with words. It looked so:

```
def parse_args():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fuzzy search in text')
parser.add_argument('-g', '--graphics', help='graphical version',
                    action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--console', help='console version', nargs=2,
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                    metavar=('TEXTFILE', 'WORDSFILE'))
return parser.parse_args()

usage: fuzzy_search.py [-h] [-g] [-c TEXTFILE WORDSFILE]

Fuzzy search in text

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -g, --graphics        graphical version
  -c TEXTFILE WORDSFILE, --console TEXTFILE WORDSFILE
                        console version
```

Now I need to rewrite the accepting of arguments in the console version. I want to add two optional arguments that will store true for register-sensitivity (-r) and special view(-v). I know how to do it but I can't understand what to do with the next thing. I want to make two variants: 1)obligatory two files with text and words like it was initially and 2) obligatory file with text and not obligatory file with words, if it's not written than default - sys.stdin. Graphics shouldn't accept any arguments. So it should look like this

```
usage: fuzzy_search.py [-h] [-g] [-c [-r] [-v] TEXTFILE WORDSFILE(if not written then sys.stdin)]
```

I tried this variant:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='versions')

parser_console = subparsers.add_parser('console', help='console version')
parser_console.add_argument('-r', '--register-check', action='store_true', help='register sensitivity')
parser_console.add_argument('-v', '--row-view', action='store_true', help='row view')
parser_console.add_argument('TEXTFILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='text file')
parser_console.add_argument('--WORDSFILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin, help='words file')

parser_graphics = subparsers.add_parser('graphics', help='graphics version')
```

But when I tried this

```
print(parser.parse_args(['console', '-r', '-v', 'text.txt','words.txt']))
```

there was an error:

```
unrecognized arguments: words.txt
```

with this

```
print(parser.parse_args(['console', '-r', '-v', 'text.txt']))
```

everything is ok:

```
Namespace(TEXTFILE=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>, WORDSFILE=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, register_check=True, row_view=True)
```

So problem somewhere in optional argument WORDSFILE and its default value. How to correct it?

Comment: Without dashes `TEXTFILE` is positional.  With dashes `--WORDSFILE` requires the flag string in addition to the file name (otherwise is uses the default).

Answer (score 0):

Use `-t` for text and `-w` for the words file. The latter with default:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='versions')

parser_console = subparsers.add_parser('console',
                                       help='console version')
parser_console.add_argument('-r', '--register-check',
                            action='store_true', help='register sensitivity')
parser_console.add_argument('-v', '--row-view', 
                            action='store_true', help='row view')
parser_console.add_argument('-t', '--textfile', 
                            type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                            help='text file')
parser_console.add_argument('-w', '--wordsfile', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                            default=sys.stdin, help='words file')


print(parser.parse_args(['console', '-r', '-v', '-t', 'text.txt',
                         '-w', 'words.txt']))

parser.parse_args(['console', '-r', '-v', '-t', 'text.txt'])
```

Output:

```
Namespace(register_check=True, row_view=True,
          textfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, 
           wordsfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='words.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)

Namespace(register_check=True, row_view=True, 
          textfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, 
          wordsfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```